# SQL - char MDDYY or MMDDYY `to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all, whats going on! First time reader, first time poster. Now that the formality's are out of the way, down to the nitty gritty.

I copied data from our core system (as400) to a SQL database so we can run our own transaction reports. I mirrored the field types to avoid any import issues, and for that reason the date field is a decimal. The date is as follows MDDYY Jan - Sep MMDDYY Oct - Dec. Heres what I have so far to be able to convert this to a date time.

```
select 
wtdate [og_date]
,len (wtdate) [length]
,case when 
        len(cast(replace(wtdate,' ','') as char)) = 5 
      then
        CONVERT(DATe,LEFT((CONVERT(VARCHAR,'0') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WTDATE)),2)+'/'+SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR,'0') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WTDATE)),3,2)+'/'+ '20' + RIGHT((CONVERT(VARCHAR,'0') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WTDATE)),2),110)
      when 
        len(cast(replace(wtdate,' ','') as char)) = 6 
      then 
        LEFT(WTDATE,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(CAST(WTDATE AS VARCHAR),3,2)+'/'+ '20' + RIGHT(WTDATE,2)
        --cast(wtdate as varchar)
      else
        'Error converting date'
 end as [convert datetime]
from 
Trans
group by wtdate
order by wtdate      


results
og_date length  convert datetime
92514   5   2014-09-25
92614   5   2014-09-26
92914   5   2014-09-29
93014   5   2014-09-30
100114  6   2014-10-01
100214  6   2014-10-02
100314  6   2014-10-03
100614  6   2014-10-06
100714  6   2014-10-07
```

The issue I'm having: Why is the whole column being converted to a date when i am only converting the ones where the length is 5 characters. It seems like it is completely ignoring the case when the length is equal to 6. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Also I am using openquery to get the information and am not sure how to convert the date before I import the data. Just throwing that out there in case someone asks why i don't just do that.

Comment: Hi guys,
Thanks for the answers they have helped tremendously! Would any of you know how I would be able to use wtdate in a where clause. For example where wtdate >= '10-01-2014' and wtdate <= '10-31-2014' I know I would have to convert it to a date in the where clause but this is not working out for me.

Nevermind , i fugured this out, I had the <= and >= reversed. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select wtdate, CONVERT(DATE,
        '20'+RIGHT(wtdate,2)
        +REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(wtdate),5,2)+'0',2))
        +LEFT(RIGHT(wtdate,4),2)
    ) AS ConvertedDate
from Trans
group by wtdate
order by wtdate
```

Comment: WOW! THANK YOU! This worked flawlessly and it seems much simpler than what i had, could you explain what is going on here?

Comment: Well, `'20'+RIGHT(wtdate,2)` takes the last two characters to compute the year. `LEFT(RIGHT(wtdate,4),2)` takes the following two characters to compute the day. The tricky part is to compute the month: `SUBSTRING(REVERSE(wtdate),5,2)` gets the first character (if the string has 5 characters) or the second character and the first character (if the string has 6 characters). I need the month to have two characters, so I append a 0 at the end, then take only the first two characters. And before concatenating the month with the year and the date, I reverse it again. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the documentation for CASE.

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

It means that a case statement returns one data type for the entire query and that data type is decided by the [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). The first branch of the CASE returns a `date` so the entire CASE will return a `date`.